# Trying to understand better "variable shadowing"

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined, shadowing

I understood it's a matter of when you have a Global variable like a primitive inside a function (local variable). The Global variable will not be overwritten by the local variable.
Like:

```
let a = 10;
function increase1(a){ 
a++; }
increase1(a);
console.log('a = ',a);
```

So that doesn't work. It gives us **a = 10**
The code bellow works, it gives us **a = 11**:

```
let a = 10;
function increase2(){
a++;}
increase2(a);
console.log('a = ',a);
```

Because it's the same as:

```
let a = 10;
a++;
console.log('a = ',a);
```

But why this behaves the same way as the increase1?

```
let a = 10;
function increase3(x){ 
x++; }
increase3(a);
console.log('a = ',a);
```

And why when I try this, I get "**undefined**"?

```
console.log('a = ',increase3(a));
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is your third example missing `let a = 10;`?

Comment: `increase3` increments only the local variable `x`, just like `increase1` increments only the local variable `a`. Sure, there is no outer variable `x` that is shadowed in this example, but that doesn't matter - the whole point of shadowing is that the functionality does not depend on what variables are defined elsewhere (outside) or not.

Comment: "*And why when I log `increase3(a)`, I get "undefined"?*" - because that's what the function call returns when the function has no `return` statement

Comment: All of the examples were supposed to be the same let a = 10;... I edited all of them. Hopefully my doubts are more clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to understand that you have 2 scopes here one is global and other is functional.
Imagine scope as a object to which each variable defined within it, is attached as a property. Here function scope is nested within global.

**Now variable lookup starts from running scope(context). If variable is not present over there it will keep on looking into outer scopes (not inner) until it finds variable or reach global scope**

Now **case 1:**

```
let a = 10;             //[[globalScope]] = {a: 10}
function increase1(a){  //[[increase1Scope]] = {a : 10} as parameters are local variable to function
a++; }                  //[[increase1Scope]] = {a: 11}
increase1(a);           //here u have passed 10 as a **value**  to increase1 param a(you havent passed global variable **"a"**  but its value)
console.log('a = ',a);  //takes value from its running scope i.e [[globalScope]] which is 10
```

**case 2:**

```
let a = 10;            //[[globalScope]] = {a: 10}
function increase2(){  //no parameters so [[increase2Scope]] = {}
a++;}                  //[[increase2Scope]] don't have a, so look into next outerscope i.e. [[globalScope]] and alter its value to [[globalScope]] = {a: 11}
increase2(a);         //as increase2() has no defined parameter so this argument of 10 wont do anything
console.log('a = ',a); //same from [[globalScope]] = {a: 11}
```

**case 3:**

```
let a = 10;             //[[globalScope]] = {a: 10}
function increase3(x){  //[[increase1Scope]] = {x: 10}
x++; }                  //[[increase1Scope]] = {x: 11}
increase3(a);           //value 10 get passed to increase3 -> x
console.log('a = ',a);  //this time [[globalScope]] = {a: 10}, so 10
```

Now, As increase3() function is not returning anything, so you are getting undefined

```
console.log('a = ',increase3(a));  //undefined
```

To get the desired result, include a return statement in function definition:

```
function increase3(x){  
  x++; 
  return x;
}
```

Hope it will help. I tried to put something into perspective.
I highly recommend you to go through below online JS book. It will certainly help.

https://javascript.info/closure

Comment: Thank you very much. But I still don't understand why the undefined happens. I tried to put the return at the end of the function and it didn't help. I will read the documentation you shared

Comment: I hope you are passing a value to function. Example:
let a=10;
function increase(x) {
    x++;
    return x;
}
console.log('a=',increase(a));

Comment: Got it! I did the return right, just like you said. And it was part of the reason for the undefined (I tested after I fixed it). The other reason I was getting undefined is because I had 2 functions with the same name. So the console was getting confused. It's just odd I didn't get any error...

Answer (score 0):

**Case-1:** This would run and give value 10, as you know values changed inside function (except of object/array won't persist) - as these are call by value and NOT reference.

```js
let a = 10;
function increase1(a){ 
a++; }
increase1(a);
console.log('a = ',a);
```

**Case-2:** This will give error, as you've nowhere defined `a`. You get the bluff/mirage that value has increased, as you were using same window for console, and value of `a` came from cache of chrome-tab. It should give error.

```js
function increase2(){
a++;}
increase2(a);
console.log('a = ',a);
```

**Case-3:** This too will give error. Just don't use same chrome-tab-console while testing with values. Try on a new one. You've not defined `a`, so how do you expect the value to be even increased?

```js
function increase3(x){ 
x++; }
increase3(a);
console.log('a = ',a);
```

Comment: All of them have the same definition of a. In my program, they were all together. I just forgot to duplicate     let a = 10; for all examples